# How come the PHP private class var is not private?

Tags: php, class, private, global

I was programming, and came across this problem:
In the code sample below, a public function sets a private varriable. Now one would expect the content of that private varriable is private, thought the $GLOBALS varriable (a superglobal) can access it, and at least read it. why? is there a way to prefent this?

```
<?PHP
error_reporting( E_ALL );

class test {
    private $test = '';

    public function test()
    {
        $this->test = 'Can u see me?'; 
    }
}

$b = new test();
$b->test();

pre( $GLOBALS['b'] );
// Result:
// test Object
// (
//     [test:test:private] => Can u see me?
// )

somefunc();
function somefunc()
{
    pre( $GLOBALS['b'] );
    // Result:
    // test Object
    // (
    //     [test:test:private] => Can u see me?
    // )
}

echo $b->test;
// Result:
// Fatal error: Cannot access private property test::$test

function pre( $a ) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $a );
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Thank you,
Jeffrey

Comment: Are you testing whether `$GLOBALS['b']->test`  throws a fatal error? Because it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private` keyword is about preventing the property/method from being accessed outside the class from the programming perspective. The service functions `print_r` and `var_dump` still able to see them.

So the reason is [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), not literal hiding the data

Comment: hmm, didn't know that... So, since $GLOBALS contains references to the object, the way to prefent for example 3th party software to see the references, is to kill it... Thanks all for the info! guess i got some work to do :)

Comment: @Jeffrey: `$GLOBALS` doesn't change the `private` keyword behaviour. It doesn't matter where you get the reference to the object from

Answer (score 0):

You can access anything in `$GLOBALS` globally, but that doesn't change the fact that the variable within the object you're getting at has its own private variables.

Simply putting an object in `$GLOBALS` doesn't magically make all of its member variables public.  That'd be insane, and break all sorts of things.  The reference to the object is what is global, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply what `GLOBALS` does. It has all variables that are currently defined in the script, no matter where or how they were defined. This includes private variables.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in functions like `pre()`, `print_r()` and `var_dump()` are for debug purposes and therefore can show you the complete structure of any object reference it can reach.
Security loophole? Maybe, simply don't let people inject code or use these commands in a production environment.